# Does onCancelled in Firebase addChildEventListener properly ends the thread if it's called?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does  onCancelled in Firebase addChildEventListener or other similar listeners take care of properly ending the background thread that it creates and all the related memory allocation issues that could possibly occur in case the process is cancelled or the activity gets destroyed?

I have looked into the documents [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html) and searched StackOverFlow, etc but haven't been able to find answer as to what is the cancellation policy in such cases. What I have found so far is that it results in an error as a form of a toast or something. Would I need to add my own handling procedure ?

example of firebase use copied from the doc:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      System.out.println("There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts");
      for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        BlogPost post = postSnapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
        System.out.println(post.getAuthor() + " - " + post.getTitle());
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
      System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
      //further action needed? 
  }
  });
```

Comment: The Firebase client takes care of its worker thread. It should in no way affect your Android code. What problem are you trying to address here? Can you reproduce the problem in a minimal piece of code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Frank, I am profiling my app and am trying to understand the memory allocations I see on the chart. This was just an item in my checklist which I wasn't sure about it. If Firebase client takes care of its worker thread, I think I have no problem with it then. Thanks for the good support you provide. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: quick question, does the onCancelled method remove the listener by default?

Comment: If you're asking me, I refer you to Frank's response, Firebase client takes care of its worker thread but I think for removing the listener you need to remove it yourself ; say when the activity is destroyed. I think in Firebase website there are examples for it. @Andrea

Comment: ok I will check them :D